# Apache Nutch 2.3.1 fetch specific MIME type documents

Tags: apache, web-crawler, nutch, mime-filter, nutch2

I have configured Apache Nutch 2.3.1 with hadoop/hbase ecosystem. I have to crawl specific documents i.e. documents having textual content only. I have found regex-urlfilter.txt to exclude MIMEs but could not find any option to specify MIME that I want to crawl. The problem in regex-url filter is that there can be many MIME types that will increase with time. So its very difficult to include all? Is there any way that I can instruct Nutch to fetch text/html documents for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL filters only work with the URL, this means that you can only assert based on that. Since the URL filters are executed before the documents are fetched/parsed there is no mimetype that could be used to allow/block URLs.

There is one other question, what happens if you specify that you want to crawl an specific mimetype but in the current crawl cycle there is no more documents with that mime type? Then the crawl will be stopped until you add more URLs to crawl (manually), or another URL is due to being fetched.

The normal approach for this is to crawl/parse everything and extract all the links (you never know when a new link matching your requirements could appear). Then only index certain mime types.

For Nutch 2.x I'm afraid there is currently no mechanism of doing this. On Nutch 1.x we have two:

- https://github.com/apache/nutch/tree/master/src/plugin/index-jexl-filter
- https://github.com/apache/nutch/tree/master/src/plugin/mimetype-filter (soon to be deprecated)

You could port either of these options into Nutch 2.x.

Comment: I want to fetch text/html only then why not I should fetch it at fetch time. It will also save my storage

Comment: Yes but still you have the problem that you cannot identify the mime type of the document until you've downloaded the URL (unless has some `.html` or similar, which exactly what the URL filter do).  What you can do is probably write a custom `HtmlParseFilter` combined with `htmlparsefilter.order` and as soon as you've the mime type you "cancel" any further processing of that URL/document. Or customise the fetcher/parser to abort on those unwanted MIME types.

Comment: Is there any drawback if I check MIME type in FetcherReducer.java class and skip that document if its MIME type is not what I want?

Comment: I don't think there is any specific drawbacks, the only issue would be that you need to maintain this modification when you update Nutch. I try normally to avoid modifying Nutch itself or swap the whole component, but this is a general advice and not specific to this change.